# Windows 10 gives error when writing to external drive past 2TB

Tags: external-hard-drive, windows-10

I have a CoolerMaster XCraft 360 with a 8TB drive in it. It's formatted using the NTFS file system. It's almost 25% full, so I'm just about to hit the magic 2TB mark. When I'm trying to copy a file to the drive, Windows 10 gives an error: `Error 0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect`.

I've found several references to that error code, but none seem to apply to my situation (either Windows Update or Windows 7-specific). I tried changing the number format setting [as described](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/982736), but that didn't solve the problem.

I'm guessing it has something to do with adressing past the 2TB mark, but I'm not sure how to get Windows to fix that problem.

Comment: How did you connect the enclosure? Via the eSATA port of did you fall back to the USB port?  Asking because I see no reason why windows 10 would not handle that natively, but when an USB to SATA bridge is in the loop all bets are off.

Comment: My new motherboard doesn't have an eSATA port, so it's connected to a USB 3.0 port.

Comment: [File path too long can cause this error also.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/0x80070057-error-when-copying-files/cbb592f6-1e50-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was in the exact same situation as OP, large (2TB+) hard drive in a USB dock, hitting the wall at 2 terabytes of data and getting the ambiguous error 0x80070057. The problem was that the **dock didn't support writing past the first 2 terabytes of a large partition.** The solution is to use a **different dock with the appropriate chipset.**

I'm not very knowledgeable about which chipsets are appropriate, but luckily I had a [Plugable](http://plugable.com/) brand dock already which worked for my 3TB drive. Plugable heavily [advertises their products' compatibility with large drives](http://plugable.com/2013/03/21/understanding-large-sata-drive-compatibility) when available. Do your research before buying one.

Comment: Nice. It seems [flashing new firmware into old Plugable docks might be needed too](http://support.plugable.com/plugable/topics/older_ubb_3_0_hdd_docks_not_working_with_3tb_drives).